# Ubuntu on HP ProLiant servers

Tags: server, system-installation, hp, raid

I am trying to install Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS on a HP ProLiant DL360e Gen8 to no avail. The installation always fails shortly after the installer partitions the disk. The SATA mode is set to AHCI. Note that this model is not certified for Ubuntu, only SLES and RHEL.

Besides, this server has a fake RAID solution called "HP Smart Array B120i". Even if I have configured a logical RAID volume, Ubuntu installer still recognizes raw disks and offer to install on them instead, and fails.

I also have some HP Z2 G4 Workstations around. Installing Ubuntu almost always resulted in a freeze. Linux Mint and elementary OS can be installed, but then suffer hanging issues during normal usage for no reason. Windows Desktop and Windows Server (virtually all versions) work perfectly on them.

What are so special about these machines? Are their hardware not abstracted to the OS by ACPI? And is there anyway to make Ubuntu work?

Comment: Are you installing Ubuntu onto a RAID device? If so, which RAID level? The OS itself cannot be installed on RAID5, though this is fine for storage.

Comment: I configured a RAID 1 volume. Ubuntu Server 20.04 installer cannot see it, but showing raw disks instead. Even when I tried CentOS 7 with HP .rpm RAID driver module loaded, the RAID volume is nowhere to be found. It is very strange.